# How do you set fields in a nested struct to their zero value?

Tags: go

Let's say I have an instance of struct `Thing1` that I want to `json.Marshal`

```
type Thing1 struct {
    A string `json:"a,omitempty"`
    B int    `json:"b,omitempty"`
    C Thing2 `json:"c,omitempty"`
}

type Thing2 struct {
    D bool `json:"d,omitempty"`
    E int  `json:"e,omitempty"`
}

...

thing1 := Thing1{
    A: "test",
    B: 42,
    C: Thing2{D: true, E: 43},
}
```

How would you write a function that takes an instance of any struct and a list of fields to redact and returns a clone (or just mutates) of the incoming object, but with the redacted fields set to their zero values?

```
redact(thing1, []string{"B", "D"})
thing1 == Thing1{
    A: "test",
    B: 0,
    C: Thing2{D: false, E: 43},
}
```

I can't use `json:"-"` as a field tag because the current ones in place are required for the query language I am using (Dgraph).

edit: not in the example, but objects inside arrays should also be redacted if applicable

Comment: use reflect. try to loop all the fields. set the value to zero value for fields that match. if a field type is map/struct, then call the same redact func recursively.

Comment: Are you doing this to remove some fields from the JSON output? Have you looked at a json-patch library, like https://github.com/evanphx/json-patch that will let you redact fields after you marshal it to JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Use reflect to manipulate the value of struct's field. Below is a proof of concept from what I have written in the comment. Since this is just a poc, you might need to adjust/modify the code to follow your needs.

This function mutate the original data. Code is self explanatory.

```
func redact(target interface{}, fieldsToModify []string) {
    // if target is not pointer, then immediately return
    // modifying struct's field requires addresable object
    addrValue := reflect.ValueOf(target)
    if addrValue.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return
    }

    // if target is not struct then immediatelly return
    // this might need to be modified as per your needs
    targetValue := addrValue.Elem()
    targetType := targetValue.Type()
    if targetType.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
        return
    }

    // loop the fields
    for i := 0; i < targetType.NumField(); i++ {
        fType := targetType.Field(i)
        fValue := targetValue.Field(i)

        // if the field type is struct, then call redact() recursively
        if fValue.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            redact(fValue.Addr().Interface(), fieldsToModify)
            continue
        } 

        // if the field is slice, loop then call redact() recursively
        if fValue.Kind() == reflect.Array || fValue.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
            for i := 0; i < fValue.Len(); i++ {
                redact(fValue.Index(i).Addr().Interface(), fieldsToModify)
            }
            continue
        }

        // loop the fieldsToModify
        for _, fieldToModify := range fieldsToModify {
            if fieldToModify == fType.Name && fValue.CanSet() {
                fValue.Set(reflect.Zero(fType.Type))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `redact()` function pointer data in first parameter, since modifying fields require addresable object.

```
type Thing2 struct {
    D bool `json:"d,omitempty"`
    E int  `json:"e,omitempty"`
}

type Thing1 struct {
    A string   `json:"a,omitempty"`
    B int      `json:"b,omitempty"`
    C Thing2   `json:"c,omitempty"`
    H []Thing2 `json:"h,omitempty"`
}

thing1 := Thing1{
    A: "test",
    B: 42,
    C: Thing2{D: true, E: 43},
    H: []Thing2{Thing2{D: true, E: 43}},
}

fmt.Printf("before: %#v \n", thing1)
// before: main.Thing1{A:"test", B:42, C:main.Thing2{D:true, E:43}, H:[]main.Thing2{main.Thing2{D:true, E:43}}} 

redact(&thing1, []string{"B", "D"})
fmt.Printf("after: %#v \n", thing1)
// after: main.Thing1{A:"test", B:0, C:main.Thing2{D:false, E:43}, H:[]main.Thing2{main.Thing2{D:false, E:43}}}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wy39DGdSVV7

Comment: Forgot to put this in the example, but objects inside arrays should also be redacted if applicable

Comment: @Iamok just updated my answer. btw like I said, it is just a poc, you might need to modify it to follow your needs

Comment: @Iamok not trying to offend, but you need to do some effort as well. try to understand the code, then imrove it

Comment: I understand. I am not just waiting for answers. I am also tinkering with the responses on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it with the reflect package:

```
func redact(x interface{}, names []string) error {
    // Starting value must be a pointer.
    v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        return errors.New("not pointer")
    }

    // Create map for easy lookup.
    m := make(map[string]bool)
    for _, name := range names {
        m[name] = true
    }

    redactValue(v, m)
    return nil
}

func redactValue(v reflect.Value, names map[string]bool) {
    switch v.Kind() {
    case reflect.Ptr:
        if v.IsZero() {
            return
        }
        redactValue(v.Elem(), names)
    case reflect.Interface:
        if v.IsZero() {
            return
        }
        iv := v.Elem()
        switch iv.Kind() {
        case reflect.Slice, reflect.Ptr:
            redactValue(iv, names)
        case reflect.Struct, reflect.Array:
            // Copy required for modification. 
            copy := reflect.New(iv.Type()).Elem()
            copy.Set(iv)
            redactValue(copy, names)
            v.Set(copy)
        }
    case reflect.Struct:
        t := v.Type()
        for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
            sf := t.Field(i)
            ft := sf.Type
            fv := v.Field(i)
            if names[sf.Name] {
                // Clobber the field.
                fv.Set(reflect.Zero(ft))
                continue
            }
            redactValue(fv, names)
        }
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
            redactValue(v.Index(i), names)
        }

    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b0n-v1u24vA).

This answer handles structs, slices, arrays, pointers and interfaces.

Comment: Forgot to put this in the example, but objects inside arrays should also be redacted if applicable